# Kotlin DSL Android Gradle Tasks

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am in process of migrating all the Groovy scripts to Kotlin DSL for our android project. Our build flavours looks like below:

```
   buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        isDebuggable = true
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("default")
    }

    create("qa") {
        isShrinkResources = true
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isUseProguard = true
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }

    getByName("release") {
        isShrinkResources = true
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isUseProguard = true
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
```

So for this works If I am looking to run of the taks from command line

```
./gradleW aDebug
./gradleW aQa
./gradleW aRelease
```

Now, the current problem is when I am trying to combine all the tasks into one below is the code how looks like in Groovy but not sure how to write in Kotlin DSL. Appreciate your help

```
//This is in Groovy        
task assembleAll(dependsOn:
            [
                    'assembleQa',
                    'assembleRelease',
            ])
```

Can you please let me know how it would look like in Kotlin DSL?
I have tried the below but not working so far.

```
task("assembleAll") {
    dependsOn("assembleQa")
    dependsOn("assembleRelease")
}
```

Comment: This is working  But is this the right way?
task("assembleAll") {
    dependsOn("assembleQa","assembleRelease")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 task("assembleAll") 
{ dependsOn("assembleQa","assembleRelease") }
```

This is the solution

Answer (score 2):

If you're converting your scripts from Gradle Groovy to Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.register("assembleAll") {
    dependsOn("assembleQa", "assembleRelease")
}
```